# Sent file with socket in java

Tags: java, file, sockets

I want to send file from client to server using socket.

But at the server, I only receive the first line. What is the problem?

Server Code

```
public static void main(String ars[]){
    int port = 1000;
    try {
        ServerSocket sercoc = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("dkjd");
        while (true){
            Socket soc = sercoc.accept();
            InputStream flux = soc.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader entree = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(flux));
            String message = entree.readLine();

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Client Code

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    String hote = "127.00.0.1";
    int port = 1000;
    FileReader input = null;
    
    File file = new File("src/view/files/temperature2.txt");
    Socket soc = null;
    try {
        soc = new Socket(hote,port);
        OutputStream flux = soc.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter sortie = new OutputStreamWriter(flux);
        try {
            input = new FileReader("src/view/files/temperature2.txt");

            char c;
            while ((c = (char) input.read()) != -1){
                sortie.write(c);

                //sortie.write("\n");
            }
        } finally {
            if (input != null){
                input.close();
            }
        }
      
        sortie.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If I use BufferedReader I found errors and I can't receive anything!

Comment: Your server reads a single line (`entree.readLine()`), if you want to see more lines, you need to read more lines. As an aside, you can do away with complexity by using `input.transferTo(sortie)`.

Comment: Also note that `char` is unsigned... So in the client code, the char `c` (in condition `(c = (char) input.read()) != -1`) will never be negative.

Answer (score 0):

in my code I have implemented the transfer of photo, txt and zip files through ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream.

code:

```
// output
ObjectOutputStream objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                     objectOutput.writeObject(your_file);


// input
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                        buffer = (byte[]) ois.readObject();
```